# Call constructor every time i access in a page Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, constructor, provider, stateless

I want to call a constructor from a class everytime i login in app, the first time it's all ok but the next times is no called.

Im using stateless widget and provider.

Elements:

1. a simple class whit a constructor

```
class FetchDataFromTheWeb extends ChangeNotifier{ 
   FetchDataFromTheWeb(){
      loadingData();
   }

   Future loadingData(){
      // And more code
   }
}
```

2. My stateless widget

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   final conferencesServices = Provider.of<FetchDataFromTheWeb>(context);
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Hello')),
         body: ListWhitFetchedData()
      );
   }
}
```

Situation:
Im login in the app and the content is loaded by the method in constructor, but if im logout and login again whit a different account the constructor is not called and the data previously loaded is kept to the new user and they need to be load manually by the new user (and this is not the idea...).

Exist the way to recharge or recall the constructor when i want?

Thanks

Comment: where from you call `FetchDataFromTheWeb ()`

Comment: It's another class from another file. That constructor it's just an example

Comment: @JahidulIslam Oh, i just see what do you want to say whit where i call the method, sorry for that. Where the stateless widget is build and the instance "conferencesServices" (i just edit that to the post) is created, the method inside of the constructor is call.

Comment: `final conferencesServices` this line call under build context and don't forget to use `changeNotifier`  in `loadingData()`